# Restricted mean survival time meta-analysis

Tags: survival, meta-analysis

I want to conduct a meta-analysis of single means. However, these means are restricted mean survival time (RMST) of cerebrospinal fluid shunt inserted to treat hydrocephalus.

For this, I have digitized published survival curves with https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/.
Then I have extracted the individual patient data with the R package [IPDfromKM](https://cran.r-project.org/package=IPDfromKM).
Finaly, I have recontructed the survival curve and calculated the RMST at 12 months as decribed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173044/how-to-compute-the-mean-survival-time.

I have yet the following RMST and associated standard error.

```
study <- c("study1", "study2", "study3", "study4", "study5")
n_patients <- c(535, 209, 111, 599, 434)
rmst_12 <- c(10.54759, 11.36175, 10.50244, 10.51183, 8.716552)
se_12 <- c(0.1463532, 0.1439506, 0.3246873, 0.1471398, 0.2374582)


> data
   study n_patients  rmst_12     se_12
1 study1        535 10.54759 0.1463532
2 study2        209 11.36175 0.1439506
3 study3        111 10.50244 0.3246873
4 study4        599 10.51183 0.1471398
5 study5        434 8.716552 0.2374582
```

Now I am performing the meta-analysis of my RMST.

```
# Compute standard deviation (SD) from standard error (SE) ----
data $ sd_12 <- data $ se_12 * sqrt (data $ n_patients)

# Download useful package
require (meta)

# Compute the meta-analysis with the metamean function ----
mm_12 <- metamean (n = n_shunts,
                mean = rmst_12,
                sd = sd_12,
                studlab = author_year, 
                data = data, 
                method.mean = "Luo",
                method.sd = "Shi",
                sm = 'MRAW',             
                random = TRUE,          
                warn = TRUE,
                prediction = TRUE,
                method.tau = "REML")

 > mm_12
Number of studies combined: k = 5
Number of observations: o = 1888

                        mean             95%-CI
Common effect model  10.5757 [10.4247; 10.7268]
Random effects model 10.3373 [ 9.4868; 11.1878]
Prediction interval          [ 7.0212; 13.6534]

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.8975 [0.2937; 7.7528]; tau = 0.9474 [0.5419; 2.7844]
 I^2 = 95.6% [92.3%; 97.5%]; H = 4.78 [3.61; 6.34]

Test of heterogeneity:
     Q d.f.  p-value
 91.39    4 < 0.0001

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- Restricted maximum-likelihood estimator for tau^2
- Q-Profile method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau
- Prediction interval based on t-distribution (df = 3)
- Untransformed (raw) means
```

Everything works fine but, I am wondering myself if this is correct and right from a methodological point of view ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS. I am unsure if it is the right place for this post.

Charles

Comment: It looks OK to me although I am not sure what a restricted mean is. There is a lot of heterogeneity but I suspect that this is only to be expected with observational data. If you have a specific concern perhaps edit it into your question?

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer that suggests other ways to use the individual-patient estimates, ways that are more straightforward than trying to work with RMST.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts.

First, I'm not sure how useful a "restricted mean survival time" is in this situation. You presumably are looking at times to failure of a shunt after implantation. That's not very useful if I were a patient contemplating a shunt, as that value lumps all those with shunts lasting more than 12 months together at 12 months. Your RMST values around 11 months could be due to ~90% lasting beyond 12 months with ~10% failing very soon after implantation, or everyone failing at 11 months, or lots of possibilities in between. So the RMST doesn't provide very useful information about the risks of having a shunt implanted. I'd be more interested in the probability of a shunt lasting at least 12 months.

Second, the power of a survival model comes primarily from the number of events, not from the number of cases. The number of events would thus seem to be a better choice for getting the standard deviation from the standard error. Meta-analysis is outside my comfort zone, so check what's the standard choice in the field for survival models.

Third, note that your Prediction Interval goes out to more than 13 months, while a restricted mean survival up to 12 months can't be more than 12 months. Something in the calculation isn't respecting the censoring at 12 months.

Instead of focusing on RMST, it might make more sense in your meta-analysis to combine survival-fraction estimates at different times after implantation, and/or estimated survival times to some survival fraction greater than 50%. I don't have experience with the [`IPDfromKM` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=IPDfromKM), but its `survreport()` function can:

> report the survival times with confidence intervals for a given vector of survival probabilities, as well as the landmark survival probabilities of interest.(for example, if set interval=6, the survival probability will be reported at every six months)

That would seem to be a more straightforward use of the individual patient estimates than working with RMST.

Comment: EdM. Thank you for your answer. My initial goal is to achieved a meta-analysis of Kaplan-Meier survival curves, of cerebro spinal fluid shunt survival as you have understand. I want to do this in order to assert for example that, the 1-year overall survival of a shunt is 80 and 5-year 65%. Such a meta-analysis has never been achieved. I have decided to try to perform such a study after this work: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1878875022014905?via%3Dihub However, most of this single curves I want to analyse don't reach the median and don't have associated...

Comment: ....patients at risk table. Thus, I came with the idea to digitised these singles curves, get individual patient data, reconstruct the single curves in order to calcul RMST at 7 times of interest, meta-analyse the RMSTs and, finalely reconstruct a summary KM curve. Being only a surgeon and not a matematician or an expert statistician, I was wondering about the correctness and rightfulness of these process.

Comment: @CharlesLDN if your interest is in things like 1-year and 5-year survival of shunts, then your meta-analysis should focus on such estimates of _survival fraction_ as a function of time. I don't see that RMST adds much to the analysis at all, particularly at an early time like 1 year, for the reasons outlined in the answer. You could also estimate times to a survival that is reached in (almost) all studies, like times to 75% or 80% survival, instead of the median survival time. There's nothing magical about the median. The bigger problem here might be different definitions of "shunt failure."

Comment: @CharlesLDN you might find [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1186/1745-6215-8-16) helpful. It discusses a potentially harder problem than yours, estimating hazard ratios from published Kaplan-Meier curves. You seem mainly to care about putting together multiple Kaplan-Meier curves, each representing reports of an individual study, without any hazard ratios to estimate. It has several suggestions for how to glean information that might be hiding in the report of a study.

Comment: @CharlesLDN [this more recent report](https://doi.org/10.7759%2Fcureus.19422) might also help, along with [this response](https://www.bmj.com/rapid-response/2011/11/02/methods-meta-analysis-reconstructing-individual-survival-times-through-anl) to [another paper](https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.a117).